# What is this underscore variables?

Tags: c++, constructor

In this https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/dcdcee5afab6e8972f1b144ef7e7e884f85e83a3/Net/samples/Ping/src/Ping.cpp sample link, the constructor is defined as

```
public:
    Ping(): 
        _helpRequested(false), 
        _icmpClient(IPAddress::IPv4),
        _repetitions(4), 
        _target("localhost")
    {
    }
```

May i know what are these _variables called? I have never seen constructors defined like this before.

Comment: those are member variables of the class.

Comment: What you're seeing is an application of one of C++'s most useful and least taught features: [The Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: This might be helpful reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Comment: TL;DR version: All member variables and base classes must be initialized before entering the body of the constructor. The Member Initializer List allows you to perform this initialization when default initialization is not good enough or unavailable.

Comment: They are variables. The author has decided to put _ in the name, because.

Comment: _"I have never seen constructors defined like this before."_ That's a pity, since it's the idiomatic way to do member variable initalizations of a class. @Silent